# converting the bitmap to imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written my own custom view, in the custom view i have done free hand drawing using canvas.. After that i've added the custom view to linear layout.. how to add the custom view to  image view.. please help me out...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7):

This question isn't that clear but if you have a Bitmap and want draw it in an ImageView you just call [ImageView.setImageBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)).

Comment: @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
            
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            
            if(item_id==3){
             canvas.drawText(AppModel.contents, 100, 100, mPaint);
            }
            else{
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                }
            
        }

Comment: how to set the above canvas into imageView??

Comment: please update question with your code , and take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918079/android-drawing-a-canvas-to-an-imageview

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can convert your custom view to `Bitmap` image by using the following snippet:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) 
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else 
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Then you can add bitmap to image view by using the following method:

```
imageview.setBitmapImage(returnedBitmap);
```