# Bitmap.createBitmap accepts only one resolution

Tags: android, bitmap

Im kinda new to Android programming, so perhaps Im missing something. In my code, im trying to create new bitmap by invoking `Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)`. It returns bitmap with size of `(-1, -1)` for any `W` and `H` other than `640x480`. Is there any reason why am I allowed to create only bitmap with fixed size?

Comment: draw bitmap with convas.

Comment: you created an empty bitmat.you can draw on it by convas.[example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918079/android-drawing-a-canvas-to-an-imageview)

Comment: Are you specifying any layout parameter? If layout parameter is wrap_content then width and height could be negative as well.

Comment: Im using this bitmap as target for processed camera frame. Still, I dont know why creating bitmap with size of 640x480 works properly (created object got same size), but using any other numbers result in creation of invalid bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)` then it will create a "mutable bitmap with the specified width and height. Its initial density is as per getDensity()". Mutable bitmaps are the once that could be modified. So, as Habib mentioned you can draw a bitmap using Canvas.