# How to fill one image with Another image in android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, overlay

For example I have an image of a shirt i want to fill this image with another image completely like filling that shirt with a design image. I have seen a lot of questions on SO but not getting proper lead.

Comment: That is not something android will do for you. You need a custom logic or supporting library to do that. See of there is a piccaso plugin for this but I doubt.

Comment: You can use framelayout for that

Comment: Check this question's answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918079/android-drawing-a-canvas-to-an-imageview