# Using canvas and bitmap in Android , how to get this image?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-bitmap

I am new in android. I am trying to draw this image(match statistic)
[image] and fill the image with color with 10% to 100% . I tried this much and  this is image[image]

this is the code

```
public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 100, 100, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 97, 97, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 97, 60, paint);

}
```

Any Suggestion will be much helpful for  me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918079/android-drawing-a-canvas-to-an-imageview

Comment: Do you have called `invalidate()` function after you click the view?

Comment: no , how do i call it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would prepare two images - fully filled and not filled (only stroke). Having that, load them as two `Bitmap` objects and then draw like that:

```
float fillProgress = 0.1f; // let's say image is 10% filled

canvas.drawBitmap(onlyStroke, 0f, 0f, null);  // draw just stroke first

canvas.save();
canvas.clipRect(
    0f,                                       // left
    getHeight() - fillProgress * getHeight(), // top
    getWidth(),                               // right
    getHeight()                               // bottom
);
canvas.drawBitmap(filled, 0f, 0f, null);      // region of filled image specified by clipRect will now be drawn on top of onlyStroke image
canvas.restore();
```

Using two images, outlined and filled e.g. below.

[image]
[image]

The code above does the following:

1. draw outline.
2. apply clip (crop) area.
3. draw filled shape with crop applied.
4. remove clip, image as desired.

[image]

Applying different clip sizes, you can get the % of fill you require. e.g.

[image]

Comment: I think some examples , to show how the two images would merge would help. This is a good way of doing it, but i think visuals would explain it better. ( +1 )

Comment: @Doomsknight better?

Comment: how do i place text at the center showing amount of % filled.

Comment: @BDudhraj it's better to create another question on StackOverflow. Or, even better, find already existing answer.

Comment: I felt creative :) Love this solution, and will make use of it in my own projects. Something I hadn't thought of. But once mentioned, made me go "oh ye... why didn't i think of that"

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev ! thats very helpful for me thnx!

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev how do I use above solution? Do I have to create custom view?

Comment: @Shrikant the simplest way to draw it would be to create a new custom View. Just extend the `View` class, override `onDraw` method and use the code above to draw on the `Canvas`.

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev How do I change canvas.clipRect() to fill image from left to right instead of bottom to top?

Comment: @Shrikant please do some simple math, it is not that complicated.